# POST http://localhost:8888/clientquote-app/backend/api/createQuote 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: angular, laravel

I am developing an client portal application. Laravel-5.8 is the backend and Angular-7 is the frontend. **I am using a POST REQUEST.**

When a client registers, an email is sent to the client for successful registration.

**ApiController**

```
public function mailSend($mainData) {
    $data = array();
    $data = array('content' => $mainData['content']);
    //print_r($mainData);exit;
    Mail::send(['text' => 'test'], $data, function($message) use ($mainData) {
        $message->to($mainData['to'])->subject
                ($mainData['subject']);
        $message->from($mainData['from']);
    });
}


public function createClientQuote(Request $request) {
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'first_name' => 'required',
                'last_name' => 'required',
                'email' => 'required|email',
                'phone' => 'required|max14',
                'business_name' => 'required',
                'truck_type' => 'required',
                'truck_required' => 'required',
                'quote_origin' => 'required',
                'quote_destination' => 'required',
                'commodity' => 'required',  
                'loading_date' => 'required',                                     
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return $this->returnResponse(false, ['error' => $validator->errors()], 1, 'Invalid Quote Data');
    }
    $input = $request->all();

   // $success = array();
    $clientquote = new ClientQuote;

    $clientquote->first_name = $input['first_name'];
    $clientquote->last_name = $input['last_name'];
    $clientquote->email = $input['email'];
    $clientquote->phone = $input['phone'];
    $clientquote->business_name = $input['business_name'];
    $clientquote->truck_required = $input['truck_type'];
    $clientquote->quote_origin = $input['quote_origin'];
    $clientquote->quote_destination = $input['quote_destination'];
    $clientquote->commodity = $input['commodity'];
    // $clientquote->weight = $input['weight'];
    $clientquote->loading_date = $input['loading_date'];
    $clientquote->save();

        $mainData = array();
        $mainData['to'] = $clientquote->toArray()['email'];
        $mainData['from'] = "support@tsllimited.com";
        $mainData['subject'] = "Client Quote";
        $mainData['content'] = "Your Quote have been successfully received. You will hear from us shortly through the provided email. Thank you!";

        $this->mailSend($mainData);

    $success = array();
    $success['clientquote']=$clientquote;


    return $this->returnResponse(true, $success, 0, 'Client Quote added successfully.');
}
```

**resources->views->tests.blade.php**

```
<?php 
echo $content; 
?>
```

**api.php**

```
Route::post('createClientQuote','ApiController@createClientQuote');
```

When I clicked on the Submit button from the frontend, I got this error in the console:

[error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJ60y.png)

Then, when I clicked on the error, it redirected me to another error page:

[error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjDad.png)

I observed that error is from the backend. I checked it carefully, but couldn't get the source. I am sure that it's a Post Request. How do I resolve it?

Comment: To check for the error, go to the `network` tab in the devtool of chrome and click on the red line (500). Devtools need to be open before you submit your form for it to log it

Comment: From your `error2` screen shot it seems that you are submitting your form as `GET` method. Try submitting form with `POST` method.

Comment: @N69S - You are right. I corrected it but got another error

Comment: @ab_ he said "when i click on the error  it redirected me to another error page", he just opened the link in another tab wich is a GET request. his form is already using POST method

Comment: First of all, when you clicked on the error in the network section you have opened a route with **GET** request in your browser's new tab, that is why you are getting this error. You should check your error log ('**storage/logs/laravel.log**' is default location) and see what is the error you are getting. You can do this also by looking at the response in the network section, just don't try to open from the console by clicking on the route.